# Bootstrap switch not rendering in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap switch in a view so in my layout file I have referenced the required files.

_Layout.Cshtml

Header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-switch.css" />
```

Footer

```
<script src="~/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

However in my view I have

```
  @Html.CheckBox("DisableBuyButton", true)
```

Then in my footer of my layout page I have the following

```
 $("[name='DisableBuyButton']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

But I am getting the following in my google chrome inspector

[image]

As you see it is showing a unexpected token import and when I click into the error it brings me to this line. I am no jquery expected so hope someone can help me.

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
```

Does someone have an idea what may be wrong

Edit 2 I have got rid of those errors but the error above still exists.

[image]

**Edit 3**

OK so now I used the cdn and its working but its put two switches beside one another.

[image]

When I clearly Have them seperated in code

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("[name='DisableBuyButton']").bootstrapSwitch();
          $("[name='IsRental']").bootstrapSwitch();

       });
</script>


<div class="col-md-10">
 <div class="form-group">
       Disable By Button
          <input type="checkbox" asp-for="DisableBuyButton" id="DisableBuyButton" />

   </div>
    <div class="form-group">

       <input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsRental" id="IsRental" />Is Rental

    </div>
```

Comment: where do you call the `wsihtml5()` function? Most of the time when I see that error it suggests that plugins which rely on jQuery have been referenced **before** the `jQuery.min.js`  file.

Comment: @MasterYoda please see edit 3 thanks

Comment: it says your import method is wrong..review the correct sytnax for it

Comment: Please see edit3 @Jana that has been fixed

Comment: is jQuery referenced and actually loaded to page? 
jQuery should be referenced before bootstrap-switch

Comment: @tomsmithweb please re read the question edit 3 explains the display has been sovled but its duplicating the switch

Comment: can you say which type you are expecting from this example http://bootstrapswitch.com/examples.html

Comment: @Jana i just want the State one

Comment: just try it  `.bootstrapSwitch('state', true, true)` ..if its not success, you have some css interruption

Comment: Try changing the jQuery selector from $("[name='DisableBuyButton']").bootstrapSwitch(); to $("#DisableBuyButton").bootstrapSwitch();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error is being thrown in the browser at `import`, I'm guessing you are using [this ES6+ version](https://github.com/Bttstrp/bootstrap-switch/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-switch.js) of `bootstrap-switch`. Unless you have a transpiler like `babel`, it's not going to work on the browser.

So use [this version](https://github.com/Bttstrp/bootstrap-switch/tree/master/dist) which has ES5 syntax and is supported currently by browsers.

(Note: Chrome's most recent version supports [ES6 modules and classes natively](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/nic61))